# What to use for PC application that needs to authenticate with Facebook?

Tags: asp.net, windows, facebook, single-page-application

I'm trying to create a Windows PC application through ASP.Net and this application will need to authenticate & post on Facebook.. I'm currently working on a test version of the application, but it's a web application so it runs on my browser.

I did some research and came across "Single Page Applications" but I'm not quiet sure that's the answer to my question. So if anyone knows what I need to use for my project you would be a life saver!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about very different technologies. Asp.net is for web applications. For a desktop application you need to use wpf or windows form application. Single page application is just a pattern-idea to create web pages.

If you want to use facebook login etc., you have to search about facebook api. Facebook api is a api to communicate with facebook.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing me with this information, exactly what I needed to know.. I dont understand why ppl dislike my questions, what's the point of Stackoverflow if everytime i ask a question it gets disliked... Anyway, thanks, i appreciate your help. Atleast now i know what I need to learn :)

Comment: Stackoverflow users, push people to ask questions more appropriate. If they see mixing of ideas, techs then they dislike. I erased my question with -3 reputation and get a badge :) Do not leave, and just try harder. When you hover the down arrow, it says "this question has no search effort and is unclear and does not useful". Your question is a little like that for a mid-senior developer.

Comment: I understand your point, problem is for us junior developers or hobbyists, when there is a mix of technologies we tend to get confused and/or completely lost, and that's when we need advice from more experienced developers.. However, I do understand what you mean regarding the "search effort" but i think my questions is about as clear as it could be :D

Anyway, i believe ppl like you are what's keeping websites like Stackoverflow alive! Thanks a million, already watching tutorials about Windows forms!! ;)